# SQLite spatial function

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

I have a SQLite database, with point and linestring geometries. Between the points(blue) and the linestring(green) is a gap, which I want to close with another line(red). The line should have angle of 90 degres to the existing line and build a connection between the point and the line.
Which are the best SQLite spatial functions to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a point(0, 0) and a linestring(2 0, 0 2), then the shortest connecting line (perpendicular) would be found by:

```
SELECT ST_ShortestLine(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)'), 
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(2 0, 0 2)'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No idea whether it is the *best*, but `ST_ClosestPoint(line, point)` looks awfully tempting.